# Asterisk AGI escape digit

Tags: asterisk, agi

How can we send escape digits programmatically to the playing file.

Say, I played a file which is 10 seconds length, but in 5 seconds I want to exit or abort the playing file.

NOTE: I used Asterisk.Net Library for the AGI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is syntax of command:

```
STREAM FILE <filename> <escape digits> [sample offset]
```

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/stream+file

You can read source code of you library if you skill allow, or you can use "exec" agi call to just send command directly.

Sorry, no way give more info based on your question.